# How to make ${port} work in express server

Tags: node.js, reactjs, visual-studio, express, node-modules

I have used this code in app.js to make to display port in console but not working
below is just part of the whole code

```
const port = 8080;
app.listen(port, () => {
    console.log("hi its listening: ${port}!");
});
```

this is the output of console

```
hi its listening: ${port}!




const express=require('express');
const app=express();
const morgan=require('morgan');

const postRoutes=require("./routes/post");

app.use(morgan("dev"));

app.use('/',postRoutes);

 const port = 8080;//process.env.PORT || 8080;
 app.listen(port, () => {
 console.log("hi its listening: ${port}!");
 });
```

It should display:

```
hi its listening: 8080
```

Answer (score 6, accepted):

You can use [template strings](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Template_literals) (with backticks - ``) or string concatenation:

```
// Template Strings example ...
console.log(`hi its listening: ${port}!`);

// String concatenation example ...
console.log('hi its listening: ' + port + '!');
```

Comment: The key here is in the symbol being used to define the start and end of the string, instead of single quote or double quote it is backtick, which is the symbol below your esc key on the keyboard (I think this is true of all keyboards? I could be wrong though).